# how to handle char to hex conversion when result is only one digit/letter?

Tags: xor

I am trying to learn to work with XOR, hex, ord and char.
I ran into trouble, when my XOR produced a hex that had only one digit, I solved it dby checking with an if an adding a zero to make it a two digit hex, otherwise when i 'joined' the list, I was missing elements and could not use it for further XOR's.
Am I doing something wrong, or this is the way it works?

```
s0='Hello World'
s1='supersecret'

def strxor (s0, s1):
    cypher_text=[]
    for i in range(0,len(s0)):
        l=hex(ord(s0[i])^ord(s1[i]))
        if len(l)==3:
            l=l[0:2]+'0'+l[2:]
        cypher_text.append(l[2:])
    return ''.join(cypher_text)
```

cypher_text=3b101c091d53320c000910

without the correction
cypher_text=3b101c91d5332c0910

Comment: What language is this? Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong.  This is the way it works.
C version below confirms your results.

```
#include <string.h>
void testss() {
  const char *s0 = "Hello World";
  const char *s1 = "supersecret";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i<strlen(s0); i++) {
    printf("%02X", ((unsigned char) s0[i]) ^ ((unsigned char) s1[i]));
    }
  printf("\n"); 
  // 3B101C091D53320C000910  testss() output
  // 3b101c091d53320c000910  OP cypher_text
  // 3b101c 91d5332 c 0 910  OP uncorrected cypher_text (my spaces inserted)
  }
```